# Rest webservice cannot deserialize date

Tags: android, spring, jpa, java-8, ormlite

I have an android application where user will input data about car. When they are done, they will press a button to sync their data. That is, on pressing the button it will call a rest webservice (Jersey) to synchronize the data with the server which will store the data in mysql. 
 I'm using hibernate/JPA/spring 4/jdk1.8 for the server side.

So basically both entity (android and server) should be same so that synchronization can take place. I'm having an issue when I'm synchronizing date. Both entity is using the same library java.util.date. Am getting this error :

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Date out of START_OBJECT token

If both side is string , I don't have any issue. I also try to put the date field to type String on server, and on the android to type Date. It throws this exception:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Any solution for this? I think the java.util on android and the one use in server side are not same.

Android Code: (am using google api client for json)

```
 public class CarClient extends AbstractGoogleJsonClient {
public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = "";

public static final String DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH = "..";
public static final String TOKEN_URL = DEFAULT_ROOT_URL + "....";
public static final String DEFAULT_BASE_URL = DEFAULT_ROOT_URL + DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH;


public CarClient(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport transport,
              com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory jsonFactory,
              com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
    this(new Builder(transport, jsonFactory, httpRequestInitializer));
}


public class MergeCar extends
        CarRequest<Car> {
    public MergeCar(Car cars) throws IOException {
        super(CarClient.this,
                HttpMethods.PUT,
                DEFAULT_BASE_URL + "car_sync",
                cars,
               Car.class);
    }

}
```

}

Android Car Entity:

```
  @DatabaseTable(tableName = "CAR_TABLE")
  public class Car implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Key("carId")
@DatabaseField(id = true, unique = true)
private String CAR_ID;
@Key("carName")
@DatabaseField
private String CAR_NAME;

@Key("createdDate")
@DatabaseField
private DATE CREATED_DATE;


  //Getters and Setters .....


}
```

Comment: print date on both side , is there any format change?

Comment: nope it's the same. When I synchronize the first time, I don't have any data on the server. The one which is on the android is send to the server and persist in DB.

Comment: error seems the object is not converted to string

Comment: I am getting this error : Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Date out of START_OBJECT token

Both server and android is of type java.util.date

Why it will try to convert to string?

Comment: can u plz post android code? and json as well?

Comment: The google library handle the json part.

Comment: i completely undersatnd that i just wanna see json structure it seemd ur model class has issues so incase u post part json of json containg date i could help you

Comment: Can you pls be more explicit? Am new to rest webservice. I drill down my code and i didnot find any json structure

Comment: dear i said the output coming from ur ur rest service , that is json isit? i need that json to be posted which u r pasering with help of gson model or any 3rd party lib correct?

Comment: carid: 1011
carname: bmw
createddate:Tue Sep 01 17:23:32 GMT+04:00 2015

Comment: this dones not seems json format? is is json?

Comment: I run my application in debug mode and i view the data send in the object car.

Comment: 'this is json format : {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}

Comment: similar type u would be having json correct can u paste that json structure?

Comment: I think i found the solution. The java.util.date on android and on plain java are the same. I'm using joda time and now am able to send the date to server.